# Teamcity and MSBuild 4.5

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

Is there any way to target framework 4.5 and use MSBuild 4.5 in Teamcity? My search so far has been vain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like JetBrains is planning on adding MSBuild 4.5 support to the next minor release of TeamCity (see issue [TW-20629](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-20629)).